# The story of Vyuha Laxmi on Lord Venkateshwara Swami's chest written before or after?

Tags: gods

If the Vyuhalaxmi took the place on Swami's chest, then why the people did not identify that it's Swami's idol?

Was the story of Vyuhalaxmi written after 12th century ( if the idol is identified in 12th century)?

Idols in Govindaraja Swami temple, Varaha swami temple and Padmavathi devi temple are brought later?